# Php mysql - order by temporary value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm

I have sql, with 4 values - ID, TEXT, LIKES, TIME. I have php page that show the posts from the sql. I want to show the "hot" posts first.

Lets say that "hot" posts are given by the formula- LIKES/TIME.

What is the most effective way to do this?

Should I make another column in the SQL, with SCORE, and I update it every few minutes? Or maybe every time that the user enter the website, he will check the scores of all the posts from the last 24 hours?

Comment: Do you also have a column with the timestamp for a given record?

Comment: Just make two queries, one for the hot posts using LIKES/TIME formula with a certain limit and other for normal posts ordered by time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply order by this way

```
Select id, text, likes, time, likes/time as score from youtable
order by score
```

if your time is a date and you need diff from actula date you can do

```
Select id, text, likes, time, likes/(curdate() - time)  as score from youtable
order by score
```

Comment: Thanks! Ps. time is date, how can I do CurrentTime-time? To check the time passed

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, count(*) as score FROM <yourtable> GROUP BY id ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

This assumes id is the primary key for the post and you want top 10 active ones.